# It happened to me -- A surface mount component got knocked off my Pi Zero W and I need to identify it as seems to have killed the WiFi

Tags: pi-zero-w

[image: Help identifying component on Pi Zero W]

All I can tell about it is that photos online show it is brown in color. Yes, I could just get a new Pi, but I match prefer to at least attempt a repair.

I did try bridging the pads to see how it would go, but the Pi would not boot in that state so removed the bridge.

Otherwise Pi does boot and function normally, but cannot identify any WiFi device.

Comment: rpiwv11_2022oct1604: https://imgur.com/a/M2r8YCL

Comment: my DVM measures the brown thing 125k.

Comment: The brown thing should be a capacitor. So the DVM starts with a smaller resistance like 60k or something, while the capacitor is charging (my guess only). After charging up, the resistance across the SMD cap is roughly 12k.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [official schematics and mechanical drawings for all RPi models here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html). Unfortunately, these are only *partial* schematics. The only way I know how to determine what your now-missing part was is to tie a reference designator on the board (e.g. C11, R5, etc) to one of the components shown on the schematic.